# Not able to insert data from django to sqlite for face detection

Tags: django, sqlite

```
def markAttendance(Name,inTime,InDate):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:

        sql = '''INSERT INTO  markAttendance(Name,inTime,InDate)
              VALUES(%s, %s, %s)'''
    
    val=(Name,inTime,InDate)
    cursor.execute(sql,val)
    
    connection.commit()

    return cur.lastrowid
```

Answer (score 0):

You work with `%s` to specify parameters:

```
with connect.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = '''INSERT INTO markAttendance(Name,inTime,InDate)
             VALUES(%s, %s, %s)'''
    val=(Name,inTime,InDate)
    cur.execute(sql,val)
```

That being said, it is often better to work with the Django ORM.

Comment: cursor.execute(sql,val)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Comment: @TusharNirmal: did you use the cursor of *Django* or one of SQLite? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/

Comment: def markAttendance(Name,inTime,InDate):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:

        sql = '''INSERT INTO  markAttendance(Name,inTime,InDate)
              VALUES(%s, %s, %s)'''
    #cur = conn.cursor()
    val=(Name,inTime,InDate)
    cursor.execute(sql,val)
    
    connection.commit()
    
    return cur.lastrowid

Comment: getting error    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed cursor.

Comment: @TusharNirmal: please *edit* the question, it looks like you are using the cursor multiple times.

Comment: def markAttendance(Name,inTime,InDate):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:

        sql = '''INSERT INTO  markAttendance(Name,inTime,InDate)
              VALUES(%s, %s, %s)'''
    
    val=(Name,inTime,InDate)
    cursor.execute(sql,val)
    
    connection.commit()
    
    return cur.lastrowid

Comment: @TusharNirmal: you need to put the `sql = ...`, `val=...`, and `cur.execute(...)` under the `with`.